# How to pass the REG QUERY value to if, then statement

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to create a batch file to check for Office 2010 Bitness. If it's x86 I want to install the x86 version of an application, and if not the x64 version.

I am running a REG QUERY to find this information out.

REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook /v Bitness

How do I pass the value across to my If/Then/Else Statement?

IF (value) EQU x86 ??? THEN

) ELSE (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%R in ('REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook /v Bitness') do (
 set "reg_value=%%R"
)
echo %reg_value%
if "%reg_value%" EQU "x86" (
  do something
) else (
 do something else
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work, but you didn't provide the output so I guessed it says x86.  You'll have to check that the key exists to start with.

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook" /v Bitness  |find "x86" >nul 
if not errorlevel 1 echo found x86
```